# Query Delta Lake Table using Athena using SymlinkTextInputFormat

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-athena, delta-lake, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-lake-formation

**Problem summary**: Failure to query data via AWS Athena on a Delta Lake table (in S3). I believe the problem happens specifically if the account has Lake Formation enabled.

**Steps to replicate:**

- Make sure you do this in a **new** AWS account, or an account which doesn't have Lake Formation enabled yet. For simplicity, just use admin permissions when logged in to the account.
- Upload a sample delta lake table. Take the contents of the directory [here](https://github.com/sharjeelbinkhalid/stackoverflow/tree/main/delta-lakeformation-athena), and upload it to an S3 bucket (SSE-S3 encrypted) of your choice

  - Make sure to update the content of the _symlink_format_manifest/manifest file to reflect your bucket name
- Setup a new Athena table (update $bucket and $prefix below)

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `superstore_delta`(
      `Category` string, 
      `SubCategory` string, 
      `Sales` string)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.SymlinkTextInputFormat' 
    OUTPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    LOCATION
      's3://$bucket/$prefix/_symlink_format_manifest/'
```

- Query the table, and you will see 20 rows of data
- Now navigate to Lake Formation

  - Since it's your first time there in this account, you'll need to set yourself as admin
  - Go to "Data lake locations", and register your S3 bucket as a location
  - Provide access to the superstore_delta table for your principal (using LF Tags)
- Query the table in Athena again. Now you will get this error:

```
    Permission denied on S3 path: s3a://$bucket/superstore_delta/part-00000-81186b2b-ee07-4543-ab15-8c8cfce2ed0d-c000.snappy.parquet
```

**Anyone else faced this issue while working with Delta Lake tables + Lake Formation?**

P.S. The querying works if I use a completely unencrypted S3 bucket, even with Lake Formation enabled

Comment: iam facing the same issue - did you ever resolve it?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? Same issue here

Comment: Unfortunately not. I was working with some AWS folks at the time, and what we established was that this just doesn't work if you have encryption on and use Lake formation. You can still query delta tables if encryption is off on the S3 bucket (even with LF). 

For us, we ended up using Hudi at that time because that worked well under the same conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely IAM role associated with Amazon S3 path (the one you are specifying in AWS Lake formation -> Data Lake location) was not explicitly added to S3 bucket resource policy with S3 Read permissions.
So this should be not the role you are querying with in Athena but the role associated with S3 location in Lake formation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the latest news, it seems that lake formation now support Table, column, row, and cell-level permissions for symlink tables.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lake-formation/latest/dg/athena-lf.html